# Function to determine if Number is Higher or Lower not Working

Tags: javascript

I have gotten every aspect of the program to work except for the hilow function.
What I am having trouble with is getting the hilow() function to do anything with the program. When I run these I can get every other aspect working. The required parts to the program are located in the comments within the hilow function. Thank you for your time.

Essentially what needs to happen is every time I hit the higher button, the number for the lowerBound number should change to whatever the computer guessed, that way the computer can zero in on what number I am thinking of.

The JS:

```
function getFieldValue(target){
    var elm = document.getElementById(target);
    var val;

    if(val != REMAINING && val >= 0){
            val = parseInt(elm.value);
    }
    else{
        val = elm.value;

    }
    return val;

}
function getCompGuess(){
    var highest = parseInt(document.getElementById("upperBound").value);
    var lower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
    var combine = (highest + lower)/2;


    document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = combine;


}


function play(){

    var remaining = getFieldValue("maxGuesses");

    var compGuess = getCompGuess();
    var compElm = document.getElementById("currentGuess");

    compElm.innerHTML = compGuess;
    document.compGuess = compGuess;
    if(remaining > 0){

        remaining -= 1;

}
    else{

        remaining = "Out of guesses";
}
    document.getElementById("REMAINING").value = remaining;

}
function correct(){

    var whatsLeft;
    whatsLeft = document.getElementById("REMAINING").value;
    if(whatsLeft >= 0){
        alert("YOU WON!!!");
    }
    else{
        alert("YOU LOSE");
    }



}

function hilow(userChoice){

    if(userChoice === "HIGHER"){
        //get the field value from the button chosen
        //if the computer guess value in the box is higher that field values 
        //just obtained
        //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower 
        //value box (use document.getElementById)



        var imLower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
        document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = imLower;
    }
    else{

        //get the field value from the upper limit box
        //if the computer guess value in the box is lower than the field         
    //value just obtained

        //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower             
    //value box (use document.getElementById)



    var imHigher = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
        document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = imHigher;
    }
        play();

}
```

and the HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="lab1script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    Upper Bound: <input type="text" id="upperBound" name="upperBound"  required> 
    <br>
    Lower Bound: <input type="text" id="lowerBound" name="lowerBound"  required> 
    <br>
    Max Guesses: <input type="text" id="maxGuesses" name="maxGuesses" > <br>
    Guesses Left: <input type="text" id="REMAINING" name="REMAINING"> <br>
    Current Guess: <input type="text" id="currentGuess" name="currentGuess"> 
    <br>

            <input type="button" name="Start" value="Start" onclick="play()"><br>
            <br>
                <input type="button" name="HIGHER" value="HIGHER" onclick="hilow()">
                <input type="button" name="LOWER" value="LOWER" onclick="hilow()">
                <input type="button" name="CORRECT" value="CORRECT" onclick="correct()">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in the question, your comments are treated as code - in general, your indenting is "haphazard" and hard to read

Comment: I edited the indents. They are proper in the actual code but I was lazy with the post. Apologies!

Comment: I got your if running on the hilow function. But i dont get what you want it to do

Comment: The hilow function should be changing either the upperBound or lowerBound number so that the computer can continue guessing until they reach whatever number the user is thinking of. When I was pressing Higher or Lower it was not guessing a second time.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right for SO to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made the fix on your html so that the `hilow()` function gets called and send the `<button>` name.

After the fact i just added the next line to change the Bounds you wanted to change

```
document.getElementById("upperBound").value = document.getElementById("currentGuess").value;
```

Ugly line but this will get the desire value and asign it to the respective bound.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```js
function getFieldValue(target) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(target);
  var val;
  if (val != REMAINING && val >= 0) {
    val = parseInt(elm.value);
  } else {
    val = elm.value;
  }
  return val;
}


function getCompGuess() {
  var highest = parseInt(document.getElementById("upperBound").value);
  var lower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
  var combine = (highest + lower) / 2;
  document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = combine;
}

function play() {
  getRemaining();
  var compGuess = getCompGuess();
  var compElm = document.getElementById("currentGuess");
  compElm.innerHTML = compGuess;
  document.compGuess = compGuess;
}

function correct() {
  var whatsLeft;
  whatsLeft = document.getElementById("REMAINING").value;
  if (whatsLeft >= 0) {
    alert("YOU WON!!!");
  } else {
    alert("YOU LOSE");
  }
}

function hilow(userChoice) {
  if (userChoice === "HIGHER") {
    //get the field value from the button chosen
    //if the computer guess value in the box is higher that field values 
    //just obtained
    //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower value 
    //box(use document.getElementById);
    document.getElementById("lowerBound").value = document.getElementById("currentGuess").value;
  } else {

    //get the field value from the upper limit box
    //if the computer guess value in the box is lower than the field value 
    //just obtained
    //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower value 
    // box(use document.getElementById);
    document.getElementById("upperBound").value = document.getElementById("currentGuess").value;
  }
  play();
}
var first = true;

function getRemaining() {
  if (first) {
    var max = getFieldValue("maxGuesses");
    first = false;
    document.getElementById("REMAINING").value = max - 1;
  } else {
    var remaining = getFieldValue("REMAINING");
    if (remaining > 0) {
      remaining -= 1;
    } else {
      remaining = "Out of guesses";
    }
    document.getElementById("REMAINING").value = remaining;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="lab1script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  Upper Bound: <input type="text" id="upperBound" name="upperBound" required>
  <br> Lower Bound: <input type="text" id="lowerBound" name="lowerBound" required>
  <br> Max Guesses: <input type="text" id="maxGuesses" name="maxGuesses"> <br> Guesses Left: <input type="text" id="REMAINING" name="REMAINING"> <br> Current Guess: <input type="text" id="currentGuess" name="currentGuess">
  <br>

  <input type="button" name="Start" value="Start" onclick="play()"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="HIGHER" value="HIGHER" onclick="hilow(name)">
  <input type="button" name="LOWER" value="LOWER" onclick="hilow(name)">
  <input type="button" name="CORRECT" value="CORRECT" onclick="correct()">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That does what i'm looking for. All I need now is to figure how to count down the guesses left. I thought I had it written correctly but it isn't counting down after every time. I'll have to work with the play() function and find an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @kantor9991 happy it helped. Hope you can upvote or accept if it helped you

Comment: Sure thing. Would you have any idea how to make the current guesses part of the code count down? I thought I had that covered in play() but it doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: @kantor9991 make your remaining variable a global var. It is resetting every time you run ``play()``

Comment: Hmm, I ended up doing that and nothing changed. I guess I'll fiddle with it.

Comment: @kantor9991 edited. Hope it helps. Ended up doing an extra function and using a flag to identify if the first iteration. Not the besto but a quick solution

Comment: I'll definitely take a look at it. For this exercise im limited to the functions I have no more, no less. I'll try and work that code into the play function. I really appreciate your help

Comment: @kantor9991 sorry if my answer didnt solved your question. May I know why you unaccepted it, is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: It did answer my question. not sure how it got unaccepted, but I rechecked it!

Answer (score 2):

First, your quotes span multiple lines and the subsequent lines aren't escaped as quotes. Thus, they get rendered as code, which throws a syntax error.

Second, you're not actually passing through the `userChoice` function parameter to your function. You're looking to pass through the `value` of the button element into your function itself with `onclick="hilow(this.value)"`.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
function getFieldValue(target) {
  var elm = document.getElementById(target);
  var val;

  if (val != REMAINING && val >= 0) {
    val = parseInt(elm.value);
  } else {
    val = elm.value;
  }
  return val;
}

function getCompGuess() {
  var highest = parseInt(document.getElementById("upperBound").value);
  var lower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
  var combine = (highest + lower) / 2;
  document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = combine;
}


function play() {
  var remaining = getFieldValue("maxGuesses");
  var compGuess = getCompGuess();
  var compElm = document.getElementById("currentGuess");

  compElm.innerHTML = compGuess;
  document.compGuess = compGuess;
  if (remaining > 0) {
    remaining -= 1;
  } else {
    remaining = "Out of guesses";
  }
  document.getElementById("REMAINING").value = remaining;
}

function correct() {
  var whatsLeft;
  whatsLeft = document.getElementById("REMAINING").value;
  if (whatsLeft >= 0) {
    alert("YOU WON!!!");
  } else {
    alert("YOU LOSE");
  }
}

function hilow(userChoice) {
  if (userChoice === "HIGHER") {
    //get the field value from the button chosen
    //if the computer guess value in the box is higher that field values just obtained
    //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower value box(use document.getElementById)
    var imLower = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
    document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = imLower;
  } else {
    //get the field value from the upper limit box
    //if the computer guess value in the box is lower than the field value just obtained
    //take the computer guess in the guess box and put it in the lower value box(use document.getElementById)
    var imHigher = parseInt(document.getElementById("lowerBound").value);
    document.getElementById("currentGuess").value = imHigher;
  }

  play();
}
```

```html
<body>

  Upper Bound: <input type="text" id="upperBound" name="upperBound" required>
  <br> Lower Bound: <input type="text" id="lowerBound" name="lowerBound" required>
  <br> Max Guesses: <input type="text" id="maxGuesses" name="maxGuesses"> <br> Guesses Left: <input type="text" id="REMAINING" name="REMAINING"> <br> Current Guess: <input type="text" id="currentGuess" name="currentGuess">
  <br>

  <input type="button" name="Start" value="Start" onclick="play()"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="HIGHER" value="HIGHER" onclick="hilow(this.value)">
  <input type="button" name="LOWER" value="LOWER" onclick="hilow(this.value)">
  <input type="button" name="CORRECT" value="CORRECT" onclick="correct()">

</body>
```

Comment: instead of ``this.value``, you could use ``name``

Comment: Considering they are both the same in this situation, yes, though you would want to be checking against the `value` property in application :)

Comment: I appreciate your answer and have cleaned up the code snippet on the post (I promise it wasnt that disgusting in reality on my text editor!) I still don't see the effect of play() being called again. It doesnt lower the count of guesses left or have the computer try again.

Comment: @ObsidianAge one thing of SO i love, is to find out how other people solve thigs. I allways stick to sending the name. Learned something new jajaja. Upvoted :)

Comment: @kantor9991 -- Not sure why `play()` was being called there myself either, but all I did was clean the code; not modify it (with the exception of adding in `.this.value`). That was already there :)